# unobfuscate code javascript on html blog

Tags: javascript, html, obfuscation, blogger, deobfuscation

is it possible to unobfuscate javascript code? (or any method) i've been tried http://jsbeautifier.org/ but this does not work

```
var _2289;var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var _3923=/[\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46]/;var _6534=2;var _7379=_8551.charAt(_8551.length-1);var _2180;var _4601=_8551.split(_3923);var _2576=[String.fromCharCode,isNaN,parseInt,String];_4601[1]=_2576_6534+1;var _2746=(_6534==7)?String:eval;_2180='';_11=_2576_6534/_2576_6534;for(_2289=3;_2289<_11;_2289++)_2180+=(_2576_6534-2/_2576_6534-_2576_6534+_2576_6534-1));var _9279='_1482';var _4132='_9279=_2180';function _1381(_6491){_2746(_9349);_1381(_2786);_2786(_4132);_1381(_9279);}var _9349='_1381=_2746';var _2786='_2786=_1381';_1381(_7379);
```

and

```
var _2246;var _6738='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';var _4299=/[\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46]/;var _8387=2;var _8995=_6738.charAt(_6738.length-1);var _1893;var _1751=_6738.split(_4299);var _9665=[String.fromCharCode,isNaN,parseInt,String];_1751[1]=_9665[_8387+1](_9665[_8387](_1751[1])/21);var _7615=(_8387==7)?String:eval;_1893='';_11=_9665[_8387](_1751[0])/_9665[_8387](_1751[1]);for(_2246=3;_2246<_11;_2246++)_1893+=(_9665[_8387-2]((_9665[_8387](_1751[_2246])+_9665[_8387](_1751[2])+_9665[_8387](_1751[1]))/_9665[_8387](_1751[1])-_9665[_8387](_1751[2])+_9665[_8387](_1751[1])-1));var _1112='_4922';var _9936='_1112=_1893';function _1153(_5321){_7615(_6481);_1153(_9798);_9798(_9936);_1153(_1112);}var _6481='_1153=_7615';var _9798='_9798=_1153';_1153(_8995);
```

thank you!

Comment: jsbeautifier works for me. The problem is the huge string.

Comment: they both do not work. Im currently trying to deobfuscate them, buts a very difficult taks...

Comment: Have a look at http://jsbin.com/temobaxofe/edit?js ...

Comment: there is No method again dude? :(

Comment: Checked the first snippet: `ReferenceError: _2576_6534 is not defined` and I see an extra `)` after the loop; something seems to be missing here. Even obfuscated code has to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Shure. Every code can be deobfuscated. However it needs some time.
Ive simply gave names to all variables, have a look at http://jsbin.com/temobaxofe/edit?js .

Lets elaborate a bit. It all starts with this line:

```
var regex=/[\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46]/;
var splitted=string.split(regex);
```

Our big string is splitted into smaller chunks, wich contain numbers. Then it is looped over:

```
 var stringtwo="";

for(var i=3;i<somenumber;i++){

 stringtwo+=(String.fromCharCode((parseInt(splitted[i])+128+5)/5-128+5-1))

};
```

So it does some math on the numbers, then converts them into a String.

The last part of the code looks ugly:

```
var some='donotcare',changesome='some=stringtwo';

function recursive(irrelevant){
  eval(rectoeval);
  recursive(anothereval);//rectoeval => recursive is actuall eval
  anothereval(changesome);//anothereval is actually recursive wich is actually eval
  recursive(some);//recursive is eval, some is stringtwo since eval(changesome)
}
var rectoeval='recursive=eval';
var anothereval='anothereval=recursive';
recursive(seven);
```

But actually it does:

```
eval(stringtwo);
```

---

Conclusion: it splits the big string, does some Math onto it, end gets a String at the end. This string is than evaled, it is just some normal jquery stuff.